# How to access related data in view ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm struggling to figure out how to access related data in my view. I think my issue has something to do with collection vs reference navigation properies, but I can't figure out what the problem is.

This app is to keep track of prototype testing, with Test and Prototype entities having a one-to-many relationship.

Test model(attributes removed):

```
public int Test_ID { get; set; }
public string Test_Name { get; set; }
public string? Test_Procedure { get; set; }
public string? Test_Notes { get; set; }

public ICollection<Prototype>? Prototype{ get; set; }
```

Prototype model:

```
public int Prototype_ID { get; set; }
public string Prototype_Name { get; set; }
public string Prototype_Model { get; set; }
public int Trials { get; set; }

public Test Test { get; set; }
```

I want to be able to view the Prototypes associated with each Test, which I've tried to do in my PrototypeController.cs:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int? id)
        {
            var test = _db.Tests
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Include(t => t.Prototypes);
            return View(await test.ToListAsync());
        }
```

And finally in my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<TortureChamber.Models.Test>
...
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var test in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td width="25%">@test.Test_Name</td>
                        @*Below is where my errors are*@
                        <td width="25%">@test.Prototypes.Prototype_Name</td>
                        <td width="25%">@test.Prototypes.Prototype_Model</td>
                        <td width="25%">@test.Prototypes.Cycles</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
```

In my view I get the error:

"CS1061 'ICollection' does not contain a definition for 'Prototype_Name' and no accessible extension method 'Prototype_Name' accepting a first argument of type 'ICollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I realize I've probably forgotten an important step. Can anyone point me to what it is?

Comment: Use nested `for`/`foreach` loop for `Prototypes` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Prototypes` is a `ICollection<Prototype>` but you're accessing it as though it's an instance of `Prototype`; it isn't, you haven't indexed into it. You probably want to either take the first member, or iterate over its contents and print a table row for each one.